# addMessageCountListener doesn't work in javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, pop3

I'm trying to use addMessageCountListener (for POP3 protocol) in a small project, but it doesn't work.

This is code where I added listener:

```
protected void openFolder() {
    try {

        this.inbox = this.store.getFolder("INBOX");

        if (inbox == null) {

            throw new Exception("No POP3 INBOX");

        }

        this.inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

        this.inbox.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountAdapter() {

            public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent ev) {

                System.out.println("Event");

                Message [] msgs = ev.getMessages();

                for (Message msg : msgs) {

                    System.out.println("msg");

                    System.out.println(AbstractReceiverClient.getTextFromMsg("email", "subject", msg));
                }
            }

            public void messagesRemoved(MessageCountEvent ev) {}
       });
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Here, I ask server for count of messages per 5 seconds.

```
public void worker() {
    try {
        while(true){
            java.lang.Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println(this.inbox.getMessageCount());
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}
```

As the result, I just see only count of messages (g.e. 18), but I've sent a message after programm was run.

PS. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the POP3 protocol doesn't allow new messages to appear in your INBOX while it's open.

Comment: Thanks. I had to add a new method refreshFolder where I close folder and get it again.

Comment: Did that worked finally ? I too want to monitor incoming and outgoing emails from device.

Answer (score -1):

yeah.... when I use the imap protocol, the addMessageCountListenner method do not work.I did not find the way to resolve this problem. So I give up the way which monitor the event, instead of polling method.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32927782)

Comment: Java Mail API is best used for SMTP protocol, yeah Java mail API can access emails or messages over POP/IMAP/SMTP protocols but you can still check that link, it may be helpful - 
1- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_imap_servers.htm
2- https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/i-need-get-all-of-my-email-addresses-out-of-imap-mailbox
3- https://medium.com/@lavishj77/guide-on-how-to-receive-emails-using-java-mail-api-a518bf172547

Many thanks,
Regards,
Saurabhshcs

Comment: You can use IMAP protocol instead of POP3 to receive new messages. Instead of polling method you can utilise IMAP IDLE feature  which allows our application to receive immediate notifications when new messages arrive in the mailbox( here we are not relying on periodic polling).
Refer this article for more details: https://medium.com/@patewarsushant/how-to-monitor-incoming-emails-in-a-spring-boot-application-indefinitely-7dabbdb74b2d